# Tree Transformations Using Visitor Pattern

Tags: java, python, tree, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

(Disclaimer:  these examples are given in the context of building a compiler, but this question is all about the Visitor pattern and does not require any knowledge of compiler theory.)  I'm going through Andrew Appel's Modern Compiler Implementation in Java to try to teach myself compiler theory (so no, this isn't homework) and I'm having trouble understanding how he wants to use the Visitor pattern to transform an AST to an IR tree.  (Note: I'm doing this in Python so I can learn Python also, which is why the upcoming examples are not in Java.)  As I understand it, the visit and accept methods in the Visitor pattern are void-typed by design, so if I have something like

```
class PlusExp(Exp):
    def __init__(self, exp_left, exp_right):
        self.exp_left = exp_left
        self.exp_right = exp_right

    def accept(self, v):
        v.visit_plus_exp(self)
```

then I would like to be able to write a visitor method like

```
def visit_plus_exp(self, plus_exp):
    return BINOP(BinOp.PLUS, 
                 plus_exp.exp_left.accept(self), 
                 plus_exp.exp_right.accept(self))
```

which would translate the two child expressions into IR and then link them up with the BINOP representing the plus expression.  Of course, this isn't possible unless I modify all the accept functions to return extra info, and that is also messy because sometimes you just want a print visitor that doesn't return anything.  Yet, this text insists that a visitor is the right way to go, and in Java at that, which means it can be done without the flexibility of Python.  I can't think of any solutions that aren't incredibly hacky - can anyone enlighten me as to the intended design?

Comment: hey I also want to study compilers...is that book a good book to study compilers???

Comment: I think it's quite good as an introduction.  It walks you through (without holding your hand) the implementation of a compiler that takes as its source a subset of Java and emits native code.  It also contains a series of advanced topics in compiler theory.

Comment: Does it cover code generation part?

Comment: Yes - see my previous comment where I said it emits native code.

Comment: You could just pass the parent node down to the child as an extra argument (so the visitor signatures are simple and consistent), and let the child apply known-to-child setters and getters on the parent to return arbitary information for the parent to use when it regains control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A SAX parser is a kind of visitor. To avoid adding a return value to the method, you can use a stack:

```
class Visitor {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();

//    . . .

    void visitPlus(PlusExp pe) {
        pe.left.accept(this);
        pe.right.accept(this);
        Node b = stack.pop();
        Node a = stack.pop();
        stack.push(new BinOp(BinOp.PLUS, a, b));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at source code of [THIS](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~varmaa/mini_c/) compiler. I think that the guy has used Visitor pattern.

Comment: Yeah, his code just implements the visit/accept functions to return values when they need to.  I could do that, and it would be cleaner in Python than Java, but I'm wondering if there isn't some intended way to do it using Visitor as prescribed.

Comment: Sorry:( I don't know if I can do any better.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I haven't read that book.

The method may be void-typed, but in Java (which the book was written for) it is also part of an object.  So, the visitor method can build up the structure in a local member variable, thus maintaining the necessary context between calls.

So, for instance, your print visitor would be appending to a StringBuilder that is held as a member variable (or as a final local variable in a method that created the visitor object -- this is fairly common in Java, where creating small anonymous-inner-class objects is a common habit).

In python, you could similarly let the visitor method access a non-method-local variable to maintain context and build the structure.  Eg, closure, or a small object.

**Update -- small bit of code added as example from comment below**

```
result = new Node();
result.left.add(n1.accept(this)); 
result.right.add(n2.accept(this)); 
return result;
```

or

```
result = new Node(); 
this.nextLoc.add(result); 
this.nextLoc = result.left; 
n1.accept(this); 
this.nextLoc = result.right; 
n2.accept(this);
```

The first is prettier (though still crappy comment example code), but the second would let you keep the void return type if you really needed to.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood - the print visitor would be very easy to build because the String representation of each node could be written to an output stream as the node is visited.  But the problem here is that if we want to build a tree, then when we are done visiting a child we have to know which parent node to attach it to, and also which property of that parent node.

Comment: It is possible I'm misunderstanding you, but it seems to me that whether you are altering the return type or altering a "next location" destination reference, the visitor code always sets the location for the result of the next (deeper) call.  (See low-quality code added to answer.)

Comment: Right - you didn't mention the location reference initially, but that is closer to what I wanted.  I had thought of that too, but I believe it is problematic (though I could be mistaken) because nextLoc is only going to point to the location that I want to set, and so assigning directly to it will not actually affect the location it points to.  Rather, I think that (at least in Python) it could be accomplished by constructing and passing a function that would set the next location, but in Java this wouldn't be possible.